# Decode Cloud Firestore data result item to NSObject

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift4

I've a cloud firebase result item:

```
let mpUserRef = db?.collection(MPUser.PROPERTY_DB)
        .whereField(MPUser.PROPERTY_FIREBASE_USER_ID, isEqualTo: firebaseUSer.uid)
        .limit(to: 1).getDocuments() { (document, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in document!.documents {
                    let mpUser = fromJsonToMpUser( userJson: "\(document.data())" )

                    if mpUser != nil{
                        delegate.mpUser = mpUser
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

And i want to decode result item in my business Object calling the method:

```
    class func fromJsonToMpUser( userJson: String ) -> MPUser?{
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do{
        let json = userJson.data(using: .utf8)!
        let mpUser = try decoder.decode(MPUser.self, from: json)
        return mpUser
    }catch{
        print("Errore while ecode Club")
        return nil
    }
}
```

But this does not work, the error message that i have is:

"The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed array around character 17." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed array around character 17.}))).

So, how can i converte cloud firestore item result in valid Json?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my question using CodableFirebase library ( https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase created by @alickbass )